# How we can use split() function on list object?

Tags: python-3.x, list, sequence

I have gene sequence with some variable length , i want to take one sequence at a time from list so that i need to apply split() function,Any other way to do this

Answer (score -1):

If you want to split at regular intervals you can use such function based on `itertools.islice`:

```
def chunks(iterable, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from iterable.
    """
    it = iter(iterable)
    while chunk := tuple(islice(it, n)):
        yield chunk
```

but if you want to split on a given sequence you could probably use the `list.index` method to find the next place to cut:

```py
def split(lst, sep):
    start = 0
    while True:
        try:
            found = lst.index(sep, start)
        except ValueError:
            yield lst[start:]
            return
        yield lst[start:found]
        start = found + 1


for line in split(["TTT", "TTT", "AAA", "TTT", "TTT", "AAA", "TTT", "TTT"], "AAA"):
    print(line)

['TTT', 'TTT']
['TTT', 'TTT']
['TTT', 'TTT']
```